how to create collapsible titles in slatejs
I have two types of elements that I render,
titleELement = {type:'title',children:[{text:"title one"}]}
paragraphElement= {type:'paragraph',children:[{text:"title description"}]}

I want when the title is clicked the paragraph is hidden,
I'm new to slate and I was thinking of adding a clickable icon on the title that would show/collapse the description but that's not possible as I cant access the editor within the element, basically something like this
case "title":
            return (
                <h4
                    className="text-xl hover:cursor-pointer relative flex items-center font-bold leading-tight mt-1 mb-3 text-neutral-900"
                    style={style}
                    {...attributes}
                    onMouseEnter={(e) => { setIsElementHovered(true) }}
                    onMouseLeave={(e) => { setIsElementHovered(false) }}
                >
                    {
                    isElementHovered 
                    && 
                    <CollapseHeaderIcon onClick={() => {
                         setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed) 
                         if(isCollapsed){
                            const currentHeading = element.type;
                            //add logic to collapse title here
                            
                         }
                    }} isCollapsed={isCollapsed} attributes={{ ...attributes }} />
                    }
                    {children}
                </h4>
            );

